# how run remote python script with STAF?

Tags: staf

How run remote python script with STAF?

In one remote server has one python script , I want to send one staf command to the remote server to run the python script.  the python script  is in '/usr/local/staf/services/wbxtf/wbxtf/python/TeleLogAgent.py' . How to run the command ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can run STAF from a python script.  It must be either C++, Java, or Perl.  Use the developer guide here: http://staf.sourceforge.net/current/stafsdg.html

Although using Java Runtime.Exec if the path doesn't change you could run the .py program from java code.